# implementing plugins loaded action hook in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My plugin code looks like below,

```
if (!current_user_can('administrator')){
function hide_post_page_options() {
//global $post;
// Set the display css property to none for add category and add tag functions
$hide_post_options = "<style type=\"text/css\"> .jaxtag { display: none; } #category-adder { display: none; } </style>";
print($hide_post_options);
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_post_page_options'  );
}
```

But when I activate I get an error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()
```

I could get around this by including the pluggable.php in capabilities.php. But I don't think doing a change in those files is a better way. Because wp_get_current_user() is a pluggable function it is only available after the plugins are loaded. Is there a way to use this without making changed to core files?

Comment: did you try using this function `get_currentuserinfo();` ?

Comment: Deactivate rest of the plugins and check. If you do not get error, find which plugins is conflicting. Specially check "Multisite Plugin Manager".

Comment: This doesn't work because you should check for the user *capability* (not role) ***inside*** the callback function. Anyways, I prefer boomShiva's approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hiding it with CSS, I would suggest you to remove it from Menu if it's not admin, that would be a WordPress approach

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'dot1_remove_dahsboard_menu', 111);

function dot1_remove_dahsboard_menu(){
   global $submenu, $menu;

   //to check array key you want to unset in your case, print the array
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($menu);
   echo "</pre>";

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($submenu);
   echo "</pre>";
   /* Unset menu array */
   if(  !current_user_can('manage_options')  ){
        unset($menu['10']);
   }

   /* Unset submenu array */
  if(  !current_user_can('manage_options')  ){
        unset($submenu['edit.php']['10']);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's some duplicated code in your Answer. Also, check [this note about roles and capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Notes).

Comment: Ya duplicate was supposed to be something else, also I've updated current_user_can argument, thanks for pointing out :)